# PHP $stmt->num_rows doesnt work by prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, oop, prepared-statement

I want to check `if ($numRows >= 1)` then it should return something.

When I use `$con->mysql("{QUERY}")`, it works.

But when I use `$stmt = $con->prepare("{QUERY}")`, it doesn't work.

Does anyone have a clue?

## Working method

```
<?php
if ($result = $con->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = 'test'")) {
    $numRows = $result->num_rows;

    echo $numRows;
}
?>
```

Result: 1

## Not working method

```
<?php
$name = 'test';

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$name = 'test';

$stmt->execute();

$numRows = $stmt->num_rows;

echo $numRows;
?>
```

Result: 0

Comment: `WHERE username = 'tst'` and you're assigning `$name = 'test';` or is that just a typo?

Comment: @Fred-ii- had to edit somethings, did edited. can you check it now?

Comment: You need to store and bind the results. See the answers in the duplicate question it was closed with (it contains a prepared statement method) and Rajdeep's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to transfer the result set from the `SELECT` query before calling the `->num_rows()` method.

```
// your code    

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();  
$numRows = $stmt->num_rows;

echo $numRows;
```

---

Here's the reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php